# Should I add the .exe inside my bootstrap package to TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs

I have a project that I had to create a bootstrap package for but I had to include the .exe inside the package because it was not available anywhere else. Should I add these to the TFS project and can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it's not recommend to add the .exe in source control. However if you insist on it, this can also be achieved. You can package the EXE with your c# program when you are ready to release it with an installer.

And as a workaround, you can also add the .exe on the deployed server.